# How to initialize pointer to pointer with premade data?

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, initialization, dynamic-arrays

I have a pointer to a pointer, since I can't pass dynamic arrays to functions.  However, if I want to initialize that pointer-to-pointer with premade data, how can I set it since {a,b,c} notation for arrays won't work for pointers?

Comment: Why you cannot pass dynamic arrays to functions? What is the functions signatures? And what do you understand by dynamic arrays? Post the relevant code, such as functions you want to use, data you want to pass, and then state the problem!

Comment: I don't want to be restricted by defining the size of the array when I pass to a function.  I want to have m by n arrays and x by y arrays.

Comment: That means, you don't know what *dynamic* array is, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
static int row1[] = {1, 2, 3};
static int row2[] = {4, 5, 6, 7};
static int row3[] = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
static int *pptr[] = {row1, row2, row3};
```

At this point, `pptr` can be assigned to an `int**`:

```
int **p = pptr;
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works.  I'm not in love with it because in the back of my head, I'm thinking there's a more elegant solution or I'm doing matrices wrong.  It works and it's intuitive though.

Comment: @BLaZuRE Given that you have the power of C++ library available to you, the choice of double-pointers to do matrices does appear suboptimal. A much better choice is a vector of vectors, because the memory will be automatically managed for you.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer is only relevant if you need a double*. Your question was edited to say pointer to pointer - if that's what you need, this answer is not relevant.]

You can do this instead:

`double fValues[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };`

The variable fValues is already a pointer - array variables without the [] are pointers to the first element of the array. This is not a dynamic array, so you don't need to allocate/free its memory.

Assuming your function that takes a double pointer looks something like this:

`void Func(double* pDbl) {...}`

you'd call it like this:

`Func(fValues);`

Answer (score 0):

You can create small dynamic arrays recursively something like this:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int* pValues;
  size_t Count;
} List;

const List ListEnd = { NULL, 0 };

List NewList(int Value, List SubList)
{
  List l;

  l.Count = SubList.Count + 1;

  if (SubList.Count == 0)
  {
    l.pValues = malloc(sizeof(int));
  }
  else
  {
    l.pValues = realloc(SubList.pValues, l.Count * sizeof(int));
  }

  if (l.pValues == NULL)
  {
    // do proper error handling here
    abort();
  }

  // moving data isn't necessary if the list elements are
  // in the reverse order
  memmove(&l.pValues[1], &l.pValues[0], SubList.Count * sizeof(int));

  l.pValues[0] = Value;

  return l;
}

void PrintDynArr(int* pValues, size_t Count)
{
  while (Count--)
  {
    printf("%d\n", *pValues++);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  int* p;

  PrintDynArr(p = NewList(1,
                  NewList(2,
                  NewList(3,
                  NewList(4, ListEnd)))).pValues,
              4);

  free(p);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Why would you do that rather than just using `std::vector`?